Hahn-Banach first geometric form proof by Haïm Brezis
My question concerns the proof of this theorem found in pages 5 to 7 of the Functional Analysis book of Haïm Brezis (theorem 1.6) :part 1, part 2
The 2 lemma using the gauge of a convex need to suppose that it contains 0, but the final proof of the theorem suppose that it doesn’t contain 0 while using these 2 lemma, I don’t understand.
Can someone help me on that please ?
